# Is there analogs of perlin noise algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, random-functions

I want to create procedure generated map, but all resources that I found talks about using of "perlin noise" algorithm. Maybe better (higher perfomance, more realistic terrain generation) analogs exist...

Comment: more realistic ? for what ? https://www.google.com/search?q=procedural+texture&source=lnms&tbm=isch

Comment: There are other noise algorithms.  One that has some nice properties is [wavelet noise](http://graphics.pixar.com/library/WaveletNoise/paper.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Noises that can help in terrain generation:

- Value Noise
- Perlin Noise
- Simplex Noise
- Wavelet Noise (Thanks for Derek Elkins)
- Worley Noise

These noises allow us to get insteresting height maps for terrain generation.

For good articles about kind of procedural noises, refer to:

[Stanford school research article](http://web.stanford.edu/~hyatt4/research/school_projects/CS448X/Categories.html)

[MSDN blog article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/hemipteran/2014/03/26/generating-noise-for-applications/)